# Property of a category transfers to a subcategory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Is there a category theory condition such that we can say when a property of a category also holds for it's sub-category?

For example, in the catgeory of groups $f$ being bijective implies it is an isomorphism, and in the sub-categories of rings, modules, algebras and so forth. However this is not the case for example for topological vector spaces.

My question is there a categorical condition (aside from simply defining a new term), that can ensure a property will hold for a sub-category?

Comment: First of all, there is no such thing in categories as a "bijection." A bijection is something that makes sense when talking about the category of sets. So we can say that a category $\mathcal C$ has a notion of bijection if there is a functor $F:\mathcal C\to \mathcal{Set},$ and then a map $m$ in $\mathcal C$ is an $F$-bijection of $F(m)$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{Set}.$ In the cases you've mentioned, there are "standard" functors $F,$ but there can be more than one such $F.$

Comment: Well they are sub-categories of $Set$, in which I can say what is a bijection by the appropriate forgetful functor.

Comment: Technically, $Group$ is not a sub-category of $Set$ because the objects in $Group$ are not sets, but sets with a binary function. Two different groups can have the same set. You can work around this with a function $F:Group\to Set$ which sends a group $(G,\times)$ to a more specific set that is not $G$, but that amounts to choosing such a Functor $F.$

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: The categories of groups, rings, modules, etc., are not subcategories of $\mathbf{Set}$. For example, a set can have more than one group structure. It looks like you're interested in properties of *concrete categories* that are *reflected* by their forgetful functors. For example, to say that a group homomorphism is an isomorphism if and only if it is a bijection, is exactly to say that the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$ reflects isomorphisms.

Comment: For example, in the category of topological spaces, the forgetful functor $(X,\tau)\to X$ does not preserve bijections, but one might be able to find another functor $F:\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ that sends homeomorphisms to bijections.

Comment: So is $Rng$ not a sub-category of $Grp$ as well (also technically)? In general, does adding a structure makes such a structure not a sub-category in the technical sense?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is that what you meant to say? I'm pretty sure a bijection on spaces induces a bijection on underlying sets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one example is that a full subcategory of an *abelian category* is again abelian (under certain additional conditions):

[Full subcategory of abelian category is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410483/full-subcategory-of-abelian-category-is-abelian)

Comment: So is the category of topological vector spaces not an abelian one?

Comment: Exactly, this category is additive, but not abelian, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001/additive-category-that-is-not-abelian), i.e., the comment by  Matt E.

Comment: Note that in the linked question there are additional conditions to ensure that the full subcategory is abelian, and these are necessary : for example, the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Ab}$ containing just the object $\mathbb{Z}$ is not abelian, and even a subcategory that is additive and has kernels and cokernels need not be abelian (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467551/full-subcategories-of-mathsfmod-r-which-are-almost-abelian)).